# google maps no PatternItem

Tags: android, google-maps

According to google maps api, **PatternItem** sits under **com.google.android.gms.maps.model** yet I am not finding this. It says it is supposed to be part of google maps sdk v2. I believe I'm using v2 but I am unable to find where it specifies this in Android Studio. Ran through [Play Services setup](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) without any success.

The gradle has *com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1* in it. I attempted to go to 11.8.0 thinking maybe it was v2 and 10.0.1 wasn't but studio said it cannot find the dependency to download.

Anyone else have any problems with getting PatternItem to appear and if so, what solution did you find? Any other ideas are also appreciated.

Comment: Looking at [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/tutorials/Polygons/app/build.gradle) it appears that PatternItem was added in version `10.2.0`.  I just tried it with version `11.4.2` and had no problem using the PatternItem class.

Comment: @DanielNugent Thank you Daniel. I wasn't able to get to 11.4.2 but I could go to do 10.2.0. Doing that got it working.